# How do I add indentation between text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have to write my homework with LaTeX, and I don't know how to add indentation inside text. I want to write my text, like this :

```
Input  : Sebuah digraf berbobot dengan bobot sisi tak negatif 
Output : Panjang lintasan terpendek dari
```

See, the upper colon and bottom colon is indented from Input and Output, but I believe their indentation value is different, because the word "Input" has 5 words, and "Output" is 6. I try to make `\indent` code and `\hspace{size}`, but is not fulfill my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with several approaches, three of which are shown below.  EDITED to show in the `framed` environment, per OP's comment.  The approaches are:

1) the `tabbing` environment described in the LaTeX User Guide and Reference Manual.  The purpose of `\kill` is to set the tab indent, but not print out the line.  This would be used if it is not the first line which governs the indent of the environment.

2) a TABstack

3) a `tabular` solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\begin{tabbing}
Output \= \kill
Input \>: Sebuah digraf berbobot dengan bobot sisi tak negatif\\
Output \>: Panjang lintasan terpendek dari 
\end{tabbing}
\begin{tabbing}
A Really Big Indent \= \kill
Input \>: Sebuah digraf berbobot dengan bobot sisi tak negatif\\
A Really Big Indent \> : blah blah\\
Output \>: Panjang lintasan terpendek dari 
\end{tabbing}
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
\setstacktabbedgap{.66ex}
\noindent\tabbedLongstack[l]{
Input &: Sebuah digraf berbobot dengan bobot sisi tak negatif\\
Output &: Panjang lintasan terpendek dari 
}
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
\tabcolsep=.6ex
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lcp{1.6in}}
Input &:& Sebuah digraf berbobot dengan bobot sisi tak negatif\\
Output &:& Panjang lintasan terpendek dari 
\end{tabular}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The disadvantage of the `tabbing` approach is that you have to know, in advance, the longest phrase that will cause the indent.  That can be avoided with the use of a TABstack, which will automatically figure out the widest entity in the first column.

The 2nd column in the first two approaches will not wrap.  If you need wrapping of the 2nd column, the `tabular` solution can work, with a `p` column in the last column.

However, none of these approaches will work across a page break.

Comment: What is the function of \= \kill ?


It works, but if I want to add more indentation size, how do I do that?

Comment: @Yagami  Please see revision

Comment: It isn't work well inside \begin{framed} code.

Comment: Okay, I will try to work again with your code.

Comment: @Yagami  I verified that all three of my approaches work within a `\begin{framed}` environment.

Comment: Okay, It works, but may I ask, if I've to write the long text inside your given code, and I write it inside \begin{framed} code, it will printed outside the frame, in other word, I must manually give \\ code to start a new line, Is there any code to make the LaTex automatic print the new line if the text reach the margin of frame?

Comment: @Yagami  The thirst option `tabular` allows you to use a `p` (paragraph) column.  In my MWE, I set it to 1.6inch width, but you can set it to what works for your margins.

Comment: Oh, I've figured it now, I just have to put \par in the end of text which "I" think reach the margin of frame? please be patient with me, I'm very beginner.

Comment: @Yagami  Practice makes perfect.  Please let me know if there is a follow-up.

Comment: Okay, I've understand now, the key is at your p  (paragraph) column, because I've put 9.6 in, it runs out of the frame, and the text will printed outside too, so when I put 5.6 in, the paragraph column exactly has same width with frame, and the text automatically go one line down if it reach the 5.6 in.